Slight Discrepancy in RGB Values Extracted Using PIL/CV2
I’m trying to extract the RGB values from an image using Python’s Pillow library on my MacBook Pro. However, the RGB values I get differ slightly from those identified using online RGB color extractors (e.g. https://www.site24x7.com/tools/color-code-picker.html). I've also tried with cv2, which gives me the same value as PIL.
For example, with the below method I get:
249, 222, 253
However, online RGB identifiers give:
255, 221, 255
Another method I tried is googling "rgb color picker" and picking a specific combination of RGB values. Then, when I screenshot the resulting colour, cv2 and PIL again give slightly different values than what I input.
See code below that I used for PIL.
from PIL import Image

image_path = "Documents/screenshots/pic.png"

try:
    with Image.open(image_path) as img:
        img = img.convert('RGB')  # Ensure RGB mode
        pixels = list(img.getdata())
        print("First 10 pixel RGB values:", pixels[:10])
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


What is "online RGB indentifiers"? And when you say "I get similar result with cv2", similar to what? I mean, you say that A≠B, and then add and "C is equal". Equal to what? It can't be to both A or B. So, cv2 gives same result as PIL, or same result as "online RGB identifiers", whatever that is? Same question for "google's tool": what is that? What result do you get.

So said otherwise, if I understand correctly, you have tested 4 different ways to get R,G,B values. You specified fully only one of them (the one using PIL). I (maybe it is just me) have no idea what are 2 others ("Google's tool", and "Online RGB identifier"). And the 4th (opencv), well I can surmise how you extract R,G,B value with opencv. I have hard time imagining that it would be different than from PIL, so it would be nice to see some code. And also to have clear value given by all 4 methods, rather than trying to guess what "different" or "similar" refer to.

@chrslg Sorry for the confusion. By online RGB identifiers I mean e.g. https://redketchup.io/color-picker and https://www.site24x7.com/tools/color-code-picker.html. cv2 gives the same result as PIL.
So cv2 = PNL != Online RGB identifiers. Thanks.

@chrslg With "Google's tool" I meant that if you google "rgb color picker" you can pick specify RGB values and it gives you the corresponding color. If i pick such a color, screenshot it, cv2 and PIL again give slightly different values than what I input.

Note that if there is a conflict between a PIL-based method, or opencv-based method and any method involvind a screenshot (since you mention one with "google's tool", tho not sure if the screen shot occurs before or after RGB component reading), you can safely bet that the screenshot based method is wrong. If there is a screenshot in the chain, then, what you read is not the RGB values of the image, but the RGB values of what is displayed on the screen. And many thing can alter that (the image viewer, some screen rendering layer, the video driver, etc.)

So, for google tool, as I said, if there is a screenshot in the process, it is not reliable (not an image viewer, contrarily to what I've first surmised. But same idea: the color picker tool may not be using the exact r,g,b color for its own display ; plus the rendering, the driver, and, since this is web, the browser, style transformation, ... plus, depending on how the screenshot is encoded, the latitude the encoding may use for compression, ...). So nothing surprising in the fact that there is a slight difference with that online-google-picker+screenshot experiment.

As for the redketchup picker, well, I can't reproduce. Whatever the image I upload, and the coordinates I try, I get exactly the same values as with PIL. So, maybe that is something with your browser rendering of images. Anyway, it sure has nothing to do with PIL. PIL just get values that are in the file (after uncompress operation)

@chrslg Thanks a lot. I had assumed that a screenshot was a "true" reproduction of the screen's pixels, but based on your explanation I understand that a number of things can go wrong along the way.

@chrslg Just out of interest, if I may ask, with PIL what do you identify this color as: https://imgur.com/cfw6bwC? I get 80, 148, 95 with PIL and 50, 150, 89 with https://redketchup.io/. Thanks a lot.

I get 80,148,95 with both PIL and redketchup.

If you screenshot an image that has been rendered by your web-browser it has been through your Mac's colour management system. If you read an on-disk PNG file via PIL or OpenCV, it has not.
